# Injecting code into executable at runtime

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, x86-64

I'm working on application (written in C++), which generate some machine code at runtime (Linux, x86-64 now, but I plan to migrate on ARM). Next it store generated code in memory and execute it by jumping to memory location. For a long time I had a problem with allocating executable memory, but I finally solved it using:

```
uint8_t *memory = mmap (NULL, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

So far it works, but I'm not sure if it's elegant way to do such things. I wonder how executable loader do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allocate executable ram in c on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125756/allocate-executable-ram-in-c-on-linux)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911993/how-to-generate-and-run-native-code-dynamically

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is essentially how executable loaders do things; in their case they perform a `mmap` of a file, not an anonymous mapping, but apart from that it's essentially the same.

Note that it's a good idea not to have both write and execute access at the same time, as it makes certain types of security exploits easier. You can use `mprotect` to adjust the protection flags after the initial mapping.

Answer (score 14):

Your solution is mostly what should be done: have the OS consider the pages as executable. However, some operating systems will enforce the so-called [W^X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX) policy, in which a page can be either writable or executable, but not both simultaneously. For such systems (namely OpenBSD, but there are modified Linux versions which do it too), your `mmap()` above will fail. So the complete solution would entail first allocating some pages with `mmap()` and `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE`, then use `mprotect()` to switch the pages to `PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC` when the code has been generated.

Even if the OS does not enforce W^X, a call to `mprotect()` is highly recommended because of cache effects (data access and execution are quite separate from each other in the CPU; you want to be sure that the CPU will use your newly written opcodes and not what was in RAM immediately before; `mprotect()` contains the necessary magic for that).